# Взять первый пост в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!
У меня есть посты в RecyclerView.
Как взять самый первый пост и привязать к нему ссылку вместо стандартного действия? Спасибо!

Comment: Что значит ссылку? Если событие то может **If(position==0){holder.view.setOnClickListener(код)}** в onBindViewHolder. А вообще лучше дополните кодом вопрос и все станет понятнее, и те кто в будущем столкнуться с теми же сложностями скажут Вам спасибо

Comment: Что за пост - все в непонятках - покажите код или хотя бы разметку